# Equation of the line perpendicular to the asymptote of the graph

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry

Find the equation of the line perpendicular to the asymptote of the graph of the function $f(x)=\displaystyle\frac{-3x+1}{x^2-2x+1}$.

Comment: Can you add your efforts in the question with an edit?

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\frac{-3x+1}{x^2-2x+1}=\frac{-3x+1}{(x-1)^2}$$
So the function has a vertical asmptote where $x=1$. The perpendicular to this asmptote is any line of the form $y=k$ where $k \in \mathbb{R}$ becuase the asmptote does not have an associated $y$ value.

Comment: Does the function have horizontal asymptote at y = $0$?

Comment: Yes, it does, I didn't consider these as you said "the asmptote" which I assumed meant the vertical one. The perpendicular line to the two horizontal asmptotes are both the same lying at $x=k \in \mathbb{R}$ as explained above.